# Top 10 percent number filtering in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm really confused the *Top 10 Percent* how works! I also googled it but didn't find an obvious explanation.
For example, in below table, I click on the *Top 10* option (of column *Percent*) and choose the *Top 10 Percent* from that dialog box. But it only shows the biggest percent!

[image]

[image]

First, how this option (only *top 10 percent*) exactly works please?
Then, why it doesn't show the top 10 percent for that *Percent* column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top X percent means:
"Show me the top Y items, where Y = X% of TotalItemCount rounded down".

So, you have 15 items.  10% of 15 is 1.5 items, which is the same as Choosing Top 1 Item.

Comment: Does rounded down cause 1.99 to be 1 too!?

Comment: Yes, it always rounds down it appears.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. The answer (just like the Microsoft Forum) is correct.